# Can we say or write : "No, it'sn't"?

Tags: contractions, responses

I know we can answer either :

- No, it's not
- No, it isn't

But is it accepted and understandable to write :

> No, it'sn't

What about saying it ?

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/15001/216106

Comment: Nobody says it, because it's unpronounceable. I don't think you need any more "logic" than that fact!

Comment: It is incorrect in writing and it is incorrect in speech.

Comment: If you are Charles Lutwidge Dodgson (aka Lewis Carroll) you may write this. If you aren't, you mayn't.

Comment: @alephzero: Do you find it harder to pronounce than *isn't* or *hadn't*?

Comment: @ruakh: I think it's harder for a native English speaker to pronounce than *isn't* or *hadn't*, or *'tisn't* or even *I'd've* or *wouldn't've*. I'm not sure why.

Comment: @LarsH: I don't think it is, except in the general way that it's harder to say things we're not used to saying. So, at best, alephzero's comment is exactly backwards: It's unpronounceable, or seems so, because nobody says it.

Comment: @ruakh There's more to it than not being used to saying it; it's similar to how the end of "Vincent" takes more effort to say clearly than the end of "Bunsen." But I would agree with you that it is pronounceable, and would be easier if we were used to it.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

An acceptable, if somewhat archaic, contraction would be

> 'tisn't

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%27tisn%27t

Comment: This is a word that I use!  I'm really curious now why it is acceptable to me and it'sn't it'sn't.  (Though, of course, 'tisn't is only acceptable to me at the beginning of a clause)

Comment: According to @Spitemaster, your answer "tisn't" can't be placed after "No", right? Like in my post, "No, 'tisn't"?

Comment: This still exists in some British English dialects as "'ti'n't." But not in written English!

Comment: `t'isn't` is not archaic in everyday speech in parts of the West of England.

Comment: @J.Khamphousone In that case, "'tisn't" is at the start of a clause (unless I'm doing my grammar wrong).  In any case, it seems alright to me.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey 'tis! (OK, t'isn't.)

Comment: _'tain't_ is heard a lot in Bristol

Comment: Just guessing, but I think the reason "'tisn't" (and "it's not", and "it isn't") are all widely accepted, but "it'sn't" isn't (though [not unheard of](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/it%27sn%27t)), is because the last puts the stress on "it", and not than on "is" or "not". And that'sn't a stress pattern most English speakers use.

Answer (score 14):

You are asking if it is acceptable to write:

> No, it'sn't

The answer is: no, it is not acceptable.

A contraction is *normally* (and *traditionally*) of *two* words, not three. So when you intend to say "it is not" you can either contract "it is" to "it's", or "is not" to "isn't".

Exceptions to this would fall under the description of *nonstandard, colloquial or dialectal* contractions - where regional dialects slur words together so they *sound* like a contraction, but strictly speaking they should not be *written* as such. True, some writers of literature use artistic licence and make their own written representations of such dialects. Generally, though, these would be pronounceable phonetically. I suggest that your example of "*it'sn't*" is neither acceptable according to the rules of grammar, nor is it a representation of any dialect. It looks like it would be pronounced as "*itsent*", and that is not anything I have ever heard as a well-travelled native British English speaker.

Comment: If you'd've posed this answer before I read [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/689/216106), I'd've agreed.

Comment: @Davo Haha brilliant. But that is more a pronunciation thing, and not correct written English. Sure, some authors creatively break the rules of written language to denote regional accents (eg "Going t'shops"), but for an English language learner it is better to learn the right way and then discover how we break all the rules in speech later :)

Comment: Acceptability depends in the main on the context, register, and situation. The word in question is definitely pronounceable. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/it%27sn%27t

Comment: @userr2684291 I don't think it is pronounceable *as written*. At the very least, any attempt to pronounce it would either not be understood or laughed at. It isn't even an attempt to write something the way it is pronounced as discussed in comments above - it is the product of someone asking if it is possible to contract three words into one.

Comment: @Davo I'dn't've thought such a contraction could have existed before reading that. Thank you

Comment: @JonM This's'gettin'a'bit'ridiculousnow.

Comment: I disagree with "A contraction is of two words, not three". In some works you see words like "couldn't've". Perhaps it's not the primary spelling but it does seem to be an acceptable alternative to many writers.

Comment: I think you're on shaky ground when you say that three-word contractions don't exist. I *wouldn't've* said that. (That's another example, along with the previous comment.) In *this* case, the specific example wouldn't be used. I also think that while pronunciation plays part of the role, the bigger issue is simply that *it isn't done* with this particular set of words.

Comment: @JasonBassford "Wouldn-t-ve" is a *nonstandard*, colloquial or dialectal contraction. You find them in wiki-dictionaries and "urban" dictionaries online, but you won't find them in much credible literature. Happy to acknowledge it as an exception, but for the scope of this site - English language learners - I think it is confusing. I doubt that an English teacher abroad would teach this to their English language students.

Comment: @Astralbee Informal language is fine for this site. Your blanket statement does as much a disservice as you think informal language would. You simply need to qualify it and say that contractions are *normally* made of two words. (And, if you want to be strict about it, *isn't* and other two-word contractions should not be used formally either.)

Comment: @JasonBassford Okay, I have added some qualification to the answer. But I think you are confusing formal-informal language with *dialects*. One can still speak formally in a regional dialect, and if someone *pronounces* a word in such a way that it audibly blends with another it does not mean they would write it as a contraction.

Comment: +1 with the clarification. But I find there to be no difference between *wouldn't've* and *isn't* syntactically or in terms of ease of pronunciation. Aside from the frequency of use and the perception of the level of formality and, therefore, acceptability. I disagree that *dialect* is the main criterion for one but against the other when it comes to common usage. It would make an interesting question of its own elsewhere.

Comment: "I wouldn't've" is fine as a way of reflecting real speech in writing. But one shouldn't confuse spelling that reflects real speech in writing with spelling that reflects that standard grammar. The standard speech for wouldn't've is: I wouldn't have. "wouldn't've" is merely a rendition of speech. And finally the way it is asked by the OP is neither standard nor written speech.

Comment: @Lambie Thanks Lambie that is what I feel also and have been trying to express.

Comment: @JasonBassford "*Wouldn't've*" seems an acceptable way of expressing in writing something that some people *do* say. "*It'sn't*", pronounced as written, is not something I have ever heard anyone say and I'd be interested to see some evidence of it being pronounced in something credible if anyone disagrees.

Comment: "O'clock" is a contraction for "o[f the ]clock", and is hardly non-standard.  It does, however, have a single apostrophe, which seems to be the critical criterion for a contraction to be "standard".

Comment: I'm fairly sure I have seen a contraction like *wouldn't've* in a published article, occurring as part of the narrative and not in quoted speech. I remember thinking, "Wow, that's extremely informal," when I read it, but it did not seem _wrong._

Answer (score 5):

It is neither accepted nor understandable to say or write that. Say **it isn't** (2 words). Or you could say "it's not".

Answer (score 5):

> ['tain't](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/'tain't) okay.

"It is not" can be contracted into a single contraction.  This contraction is different from the one proposed by the original poster.  According to Merriam-Webster, "'tain't" is at least 245 years old.  Because it includes "ain't", it is not Standard English.

Comment: "'tain't" is probably more acceptable in American English than British English.

Comment: @MartinBonner : That's 'coz AmE is tainted.